# Не выполняется цикл python

Tags: python

```
l=     [1]
x=      1

while (len(l) != 10001):
    index = 0
    for i in l:
        if (x % i != 0):
            index += 1
    if (index == len(l)):
        l.append(x)
    else:
        x += 1

print(l)
```

Прикол программы в поиске простых чисел и занос их в единый список, но она выдает пустоту. Ошибок никаких не выдает и в логической части вроде бы не накосячил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо начинать с `2` а не `1`, потому что все целые числа делятся на 1 без остатка

```
l=     [2]
x=      2
```